# It beats the alternative

Tags: usage

In the book "*How an economy grows and why it crashes*" by Peter D. Schiff, page 4, paragraph 2 has the sentence

> Wake, fish, eat, sleep. Not much of a life, but hey, it beats the alternative.

For '**it beats the alternative**', who beat who and who won?

Comment: This routine is not much of a life but is definitely better than death.

Comment: Someone said to Voltaire, "Life is hard." Voltaire replied, "Compared to what?" (Commonly attributed to the French philosopher)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> X beats Y

means

> X is better than Y

In your example, "Wake,fish,eat,sleep" is better. However, the "Y" (the alternative) is missing (at least in your quote). Maybe Y = being dead.

*Edited to add:* **I found the original page of the book.** The meaning is obvious: there is no technology available, no supermarkets, no anything, except the water with fish. No fishing = no eating = death.

Answer (score 9):

The alternative to life is death.

Not much of a life, but life is better than death.

"It beats the alternative" is a phrase I've used for many years, but I didn't know the origin. [This Article](https://www.thepostsearchlight.com/2011/09/20/growing-older-sure-beats-the-alternative/) gives a possible source.

> Finally, I read a quote of Billy Casper’s, a really good golfer in the
>   1960’s. Age seemed to have brought upon him something known as
>   Furniture Disease. I think I have a little case of that. What may you
>   ask is Furniture Disease?
>
> That’s the place and time in life that you get to when your chest
>   begins to slide into your drawers. Oh the woes of getting older; but
>   remember, it beats the alternative!

Comment: I agree with virolino's first version, it's not clear what's the alternative in the context provided. Why do you discard a different way of living as an alternative: wake, go to work, work, buy food, eat, more work, return home, buy more food, dinner, sleep.

Comment: Because "it's not much of a life but it beats the alternative" is a reference to an old joke.

Comment: Ah, you think that it references "Getting old sucks ... but it beats the alternative"

Comment: Yes, I think the exact match of the phrasing is strongly suggestive!